Implementing mTLS
I have a site deployed on vercel and I want add an mTLS layer is there anyway I can use cloudflare? If not how else should I implement authenticate devices/browsers of clients before logging into the site?
I tried following instructions on the docs but the header isn't being forwarded to the origin

Searching "Cloudflare mTLS" returns this result which looks like exactly what you want https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/client-certificates/enable-mtls/
